# Strange video issues - works with kernel 5.14.9 but fails with 5.16.rc3?

Tags: kernel, video

I have a project G4L that works with syslinux, grub4dos and grub2 setups.
Boot and running works fine with the 5.14.9 kernel in all of them, but testing the 5.15.rc3 the video on some modes gives a small video area at top that seems to show multiple copies of screen distorted diagonally across screen. Totally unusable.
With syslinux boot setup the 5.15.rc3 boots in 640x480 default mode, but booting with `vga=ask` and selecting mode 315 (800x600) it shows distorted video with link 3 copies of screen.

With flash boot using regular USB boot with grub4dos. It boots fine with normal mode, but `vga=ask` comes up with prompt, but selecting 315 (800x600) gives about 1/4 section at top of screen with many tiny distorted versions going across top??

With flash boot using UEFI boot using grub2 even regular boot results in distorted screen??

Everything works in all modes with 5.14.9 versions?
These are the difference I found in the .config files between 5.14.9 and 5.15.rc3?
Lines with < are lines that were removed from the 5.14.9
Lines with NEW where lines added after the make oldconfig and selected prompted default options for the changes?

```
< CONFIG_PRINTK_NMI=y
NEW CONFIG_ARCH_NR_GPIO=1024
NEW CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS_AMD_UNCORE=y
< CONFIG_X86_SYSFB=y
NEW CONFIG_SYSFB=y
NEW CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS_SUPPORT=y
NEW CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_PARANOID_L1D_FLUSH=y
< CONFIG_BLK_SCSI_REQUEST=y
< CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG=y
NEW CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG_COMMON=y
< CONFIG_BLK_CMDLINE_PARSER=y
NEW CONFIG_BLOCK_HOLDER_DEPRECATED=y
NEW CONFIG_AF_UNIX_OOB=y
NEW CONFIG_SCSI_COMMON=y
NEW CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG=y
< CONFIG_CS89x0=y
< CONFIG_CS89x0_PLATFORM=y
NEW CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_LITEX=y
NEW CONFIG_PTP_1588_CLOCK_OPTIONAL=y
NEW CONFIG_INTEL_PUNIT_IPC=y
< CONFIG_INTEL_PUNIT_IPC=y
< CONFIG_MANDATORY_FILE_LOCKING=y
NEW CONFIG_SMBFS_COMMON=y
< CONFIG_CRYPTO_LIB_ARC4=y
< CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS_SUPPORT=y
```

Have been building kernels since 2004, and usually haven't had major issues in testing, but just got the UEFI process working with the UEFI boot. The 640x480 mode is OK, but a little higher resolution is nice. In UEFI mode, it actually boot in a really high resolution mode, and haven't found a way to modify it. But that works with the 5.14.9 versions.

Perhaps this is just since it is an RC version and will be resolved, but not clear with something working with one version, and not with the next. Asked at kernel.org page, and got recommended to ask question here??

Perhaps some with greater knowledge of kernel builds would know exactly what issue might be. All booting uses the same ramdisk.lzma, so kernel is the only difference.

Comment: -rc3 is a release candidate which means bugs and/or regressions are likely. If you want to help kernel development, please run git bisect and find a bad commit. After that let kernel developers know about that via LKML or bugzilla.kernel.org. Please use `diff -u` in the future.

Comment: Problem is: I've gone back to 5.15.rc1 and it does the same thing. So it isn't something that happened between different versions of the same kernel.

Comment: 5.14.9 and earlier versions all work fine with syslinux USB boot, grub4dos USB boot, grub2 UEFI USB boot, and have not tested grub4dos UEFI USB boot.
5.15.rc3 and have not tested 5.15.rc1 and they both do the same distorted video of about 1/4" at top of screen

Comment: Found a solution, but no clue why it works. Just tried various things.
Unsetting two values seems to make the kernel not create the distorted video.
< CONFIG_FB_VGA16=y
> # CONFIG_FB_VGA16 is not set
< CONFIG_FB_VIRTUAL=y
> # CONFIG_FB_VIRTUAL is not set
Perhaps someone can see why it fixes it?